# What's the best way to create a list of tuples containing values taken from an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have three arrays/lists:

```
list1 = range(1,10)
list2 = range(1,10)
list3 = range(1,10)
```

I want to create an list of tuples containing an assortment of each of the values in my three lists. Essentially I want an output such as:

```
combo = [(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3) ... (1,4,2), (1,4,3) ... (4,5,4), (4,5,5) ... (10,10,9), (10,10,10)]
```

It seems like such as simple problem, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Are you looking for permutations/combinations of three for the numbers 1-10?

Comment: Take a look at the `itertools` module https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: Just a heads up, `range(1,10)` will generate the numbers `1,2,3,...,7,8,9` -- 10 *will not* be included -- if you want that, you might change the end to 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the Cartesian product of lists:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(list1, list2, list3))
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (1, 1, 4),
 (1, 1, 5),
 (1, 1, 6),
 (1, 1, 7),
 (1, 1, 8),
 (1, 1, 9),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 3)
 ...
```

`itertools.product(list1, list2, list3)` returns a generator object - only when you iterate over it will the tuples be returned. In the example code above, `list` is used to read the contents of the generator into a Python list.

Note that you can also use the `repeat` parameter of `itertools` which is much neater when your lists range over the same elements:

```
list(itertools.product(list1, repeat=3))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), 3)` also work?

Comment: @zachgates: it's not quite the same thing, e.g. `(1, 2, 1) in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), 3))` is `False`

Comment: Ahah. Cartesian product was the keyword I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you want a Cartesian product of 3 lists? Well, there is a function for that in `itertools`

```
import itertools

result = list(itertools.product(list1, list2, list3))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also just create a list and append to it using nested loops. Just remember that if you also want the number 10, you need to change your range to `range(1, 11)` so that it stops at the number 11. It's like a < 11 (Doesn't include the number 11).

```
combo = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    for j in range(1, 11):
        for k in range(1, 11):
            a = (i, j, k)
            combo.append(a)
```

Comment: This comes close to working, although the itertools.product method is better.  Note that your range functions leave off the number 10.

Comment: It's what the OP used (and I know, it's how the `range` works). How is it that it only comes *close to working*?

Comment: You don't have the number 10.  You are correct that the OP made the same mistake, but it wouldn't give the desired output.

Comment: Sure. I'll go ahead and change it.

Answer (score -3):

Use this :

```
combo=[]
for i in range(1,11):
  for j in range(1,11):
    for k in range(1,11):
      combo.append( (i,j,k) )
```